# Fade in effect delay per element

Tags: jquery, css

bit of a stab in the dark this one !

I've been looking everywhere to try and find something to replicate the load effect on this nice site
http://www.alectia.com/

This site fails if JS is switched off - so am not looking for exact replica :-)

there are plenty of fade in effects (animate css etc) out there and some nice onload ones in CoDrops - but they all affect all elements at the same time - does anyone know of a library / way to animate items sequentially so they load in as the site above?

Thanks in advance
.ben.

Answer (score 0):

Some links that you will need [Transformations](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp)
AND [CSS CHEAT SHEET](http://www.justinaguilar.com/animations/). Both are great to work with if you want to dodge the JS approach. HOWEVER. JS and css annimations go well together if you want it to be coordinated. So you're a little compromised. 
Basically, you have your css annimations in your css file and call it on page load or whenever you want to animate it. In the cheat sheet link they demonstrate it but here it is in any case

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('#animatedElement').each(function(){
    var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;

    var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (imagePos < topOfWindow+400) {
            $(this).addClass("slideUp");
        }
    });
});
//This handles annimations over scrolling
$('#animatedElement').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("slideUp");
});//This handles annimations on click
And finally 
$(document).ready(function(){
$(this).addClass("slideUp");
});//page load. :)
```

what you can also look into if the css doesn't work out so great(remember browser support can become any mans nighmare) is to look into JS animations. Heres a link to that. 
[JQuery annimations](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_animate.asp)

And for your actual question. To have all elements animate at the same time

```
function AnimateEverything(){
var AllElements = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for(var i =0; i < AllElements.length; i++){
$(AllElements[i].addClass('cssAnimationClass');//I would suggest this one.
//or..
$(AllElements[i].annimate(//annimation of choice..
)}
};
```

basically get all the divs in the page and make them animate.

Comment: Hi - thanks so much for your response. One thing is that I don't want all items animated at the same time - but staggered, like in the example URL above - all the animate.css things I try apply to all items and they all execute on load. I'd like to replicate the 'flow' of the example URL if possible.

Comment: http://www.jqueryrain.com/example/jquery-animation-example/
You would need to wrap your content in one div and call the animation of choice. I'm a sucker for trying to reinvent the wheel. Hope this helps you out